# Can I cap this bow vent?

Tags: vent

I am removing a kitchen from a basement which had an island sink. I will be leaving only the sink along the wall which has its own vent.  Can I just cut both legs of the bow vent and cap it flush with the concrete floor?  I don't know where these lines tie in to the header but would it be safe to assume that nothing else would vent through this line? Thanks.

[image: Island sink bow vent]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unlikely that anything upstream also vents through that line. It looks like modern pipe in a modern home, so we can presume that it met code.

Yes, you can cap them. There are no rules against pipe stubs that would prohibit doing so, to my knowledge.